# Fail to download python package

Tags: python, windows, numpy

I have recently installed python 3 in my windows 8 computer. 
When I try to download the numpy package using pip from the command line, it's not working.

Here's a sample of the output:

```
f:\python\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution 
option: 'define_macros'
warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building py_modules sources
building library "npymath" sources
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
error: Could not initialize compiler instance: do you have Visual Studio
installed?  If you are trying to build with MinGW, please use "python setup.py
build -c mingw32" instead.  If you have Visual Studio installed, check it is
correctly installed, and the right version (VS 2008 for python 2.6, 2.7 and 3.2,
VS 2010 for >= 3.3).
```

Original exception was:

```
[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'F:\\Visual Studio\\VC\\PlatformSDK\\lib', and the Compiler class was MSVCCompiler
```

and

```
"f:\python\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\MATRIX~1.MAT\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rxex02t4\\numpy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();
```

At First, it shows the download of the package, which seems to be downloaded correctly, only during the installation process that I see some errors...

Comment: Install [Visual Studio Community 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017).

Comment: It is **very** difficult to install `numpy` on windows without using `conda`. You should use `conda` unless you love pain.

Comment: You could also with the pre-builds [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)

Answer (score 0):

Numpy has several components which need to be compiled, hence you need a C++ compiler such as the one from Visual Studio installed:

```
error: Could not initialize compiler instance: do you have Visual Studio installed?
```

It is usually easier to use [the Python Extension Packages provided by Christoph Gohlke](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) or a Python distribution such as [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/) on Windows, which will provide the binaries for you.